# Random error in Mumbai: MetaMask - RPC Error: Non-200 status code: '404'

Tags: rpc, metamask

I'm buidiling a DApp with the Polygon testnet (Mumabi). I need to interact with my smart contract calling some method like in the following script

```
const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
var tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi ,provider);
const data = await marketContract.fetchItemsCreated()
```

However, I sometimes get this error

> MetaMask - RPC Error: Non-200 status code: '404'
> code: -32603
> data:
> error: "Not Found"
> message: "Not Found"
> statusCode: 404

I failed to figure out in which case this error occurs: It looks like to be happening random.

I couldn't find any reference to this specific error.
I really appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score -1):

I think the RPC url for deploying smartcontracts is diffrent from RPC url set on metamask wallet for matic mumbai network try to use same RPC url. It solved my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).